# building jQuery plugin , Object is not passing to 'each' function

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm building a jQuery plugin . the initial code is like this :

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
   Object.create = function(obj) {
    function F() {};
    F.prototype = obj;
    return new F();
};

}(function($, window, document, undefined) {
var Datatable = {
    init: function(options, elem) {
      console.log(options);
        var self = this;
        self.elem = elem;
        self.$elem = $(elem);
    //  if (typeof options !== 'string') {
            self.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.SonalDataTable.options,   options);
    //  }
        console.log(self.options);
        self.cycle();
    },
    cycle: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.buildTable();
    },
    buildTable: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.getTableInfo();
    },
    getTableInfo: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON(self.options.url + 'initiate', function(data) {
            //   this.options.table = data;
            console.log(self.options);
        });
    }
};
$.fn.SonalDataTable = function(Opt) {

  console.log(Opt); // Pos1  : it shows every object that i pass like { test : 'it is a real test'}

    return this.each(function(Opt) {
      console.log(Opt); // Pos2 : it Only and Only shows 0;
        var datatable = Object.create(Datatable);

        datatable.init(Opt, this);
        //console.log(datatable);
    });
};
$.fn.SonalDataTable.options = {
    create: 'new',
    delet: 'trash',
    url: window.location.href,
    table: {

        limit: 10
        }

};
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

in above code there are 2 places in comments named Pos1: and Pos2: , as you see in Pos1 i can see what ever I pass to this plugin in console log but at Pos2 only i can see 0 in teh console log. what's my problem . whay I can not pass 'Opt' to 'each' function ?

Problem is in this part of code :

```
 $.fn.SonalDataTable = function(Opt) {

console.log(Opt); // Pos1  : it shows every object that i pass like { test :   'it is a real test'}

  return this.each(function(Opt) {
  console.log(Opt); // Pos2 : it Only and Only shows 0;
    var datatable = Object.create(Datatable);

    datatable.init(Opt, this);
    //console.log(datatable);
 });
};
```

my problem is this that i can not pass the 'Opt' object to 'this.each' function.

Comment: Ive read this question 4 times and I'm lost. Why do you have a function taking parameter `Opt` and then within it another parameter of a function `Opt`? You realise one will hide the other? What is the code supposed to do? There is no clear statement of the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Yeah, didnt help much. But on about the 7th read through I think I finally understood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do my best to describe why what you're seeing is exactly as expected.

Lets start here:

```
$.fn.SonalDataTable = function(Opt) {

  console.log(Opt); // Pos1  : it shows every object that i pass like { test : 'it is a real test'}
   ...
```

Lets remove the context of a JQuery plugin and just make this any old function

```
function SonalTestFunction(Opt)
{
    console.log(Opt);
}
```

Here you have a function which takes a single parameter `Opt` and whatever is passed in will be written to the console.

```
SonalTestFunction(42); // writes "42" to the console
SonalTestFunction({foo:"bar"}); // writes "{foo:"bar"}" to the console
```

Now, lets look at the second function, again in total isolation:

```
return this.each(function(Opt) {
  console.log(Opt); // Pos2 : it Only and Only shows 0;     
});
```

In this case you're calling the JQuery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function, which itself takes a "callback" function which is called for every element in the jquery array. The parameters of this callback are

- the index of the item
- the item itself (not seen in your example)

This should tell you why you're only seeing the output "0" here - theremust only be one element in the array you're calling `each` on, and it's index is `0`.

You have re-used a parameter name, which is fine, but you're doing it nested within the first function - I suspect you expected the value to be passed through, but it is not - instead the second usage hides the first.

---

Insofar as fixing your code, I expect what you were trying to do was this:

```
$.fn.SonalDataTable = function(Opt) {

    console.log(Opt); // Pos1  : it shows every object that i pass like { test :   'it is a real test'}

    return this.each(function(i) { // note use of more appropriate variable, which does not hide the earlier use of Opt
         console.log(Opt); // Pos2 : will now show what you expect
        var datatable = Object.create(Datatable);

        datatable.init(Opt, this);
     });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the first argument of `each` callback is `index` of array.

You are using the name `Opt` for that argument name and therefore using a completely different `Opt` variable inside the `each`.

Assuming you are only using one element in your selector collection when initializing the plugin that `0` you are seeing is the index of the element in the collection

Change:

```
return this.each(function(Opt)
```

To:

```
return this.each(function(/*[index, [element]]*/)
// i commented out the optional arguments since you aren't using them
```